# How can I use the input function to ask for the Pathname and save it within double quotes instead of single quotes?

Tags: python, path, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have this line of code:
`pathname = input("Insert path of h5 file here: ")`
When I run this line, I paste the Pathname I wish and then that is passed in the **pathname** variable.

When I type **pathname** on my console to see what has been passed I see that the path of the file has been passed with single quotes like...
'pathname'
whereas I want to save it in the **pathname** variable with double quotes like...
"pathname".

I've tried many things such as using the .replace() function but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to do this? Python should be able to open a file by pathname regardless of whether it is shown in the console with single or double quotes. The single quotes in the console just show that the value of `pathname` is a string. If you really want to store literal double quote characters inside your pathname variable then you can provide them with an escape character as " instead of " which will save a literal double quote character.